# To find number of solutions of $2^x+3^x+4^x-5^x=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

To find number of solutions of $2^x+3^x+4^x-5^x=0$. i want to do this using graphs only. i can plot graphs of individual tems but how to plot graph of sum of these terms

thanks

Comment: I'm not understanding... are you asking how to graph this *by hand*?  If so, why specifically using graphs and not using more of an analytical approach?  Any graphing calculator software will be more than capable of graphing the sum of exponentials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can write it as $2^x+3^x+4^x = 5^x$

$$\underbrace{\left(\frac{2}{4.5}\right)^x+\left(\frac{3}{4.5}\right)^x+\left(\frac{4}{4.5}\right)^x}_{\bf{strictly\; dercreasing \; fun.}} = \underbrace{\left(\frac{5}{4.5}\right)^x}_{\bf{strictly\; increasing \; fun.}}$$

Drawing  graph you can easily seen left side is a combination of strictly decreasing function

and right side is a strictly increasing function.

So these two function intersect each other exactly one point

Comment: how rhs is strictly increasing

Comment: You can draw graph in coordinate axis.

Comment: rhs is less than 1 but

Comment: I think conceptualy (slightly) simpler to divide both sides by $5^x$ and argue on the fact that  the LHS is continuous ans strictly decreasing from $3$ to $0+$, thus takes up the value $1$ for exactly one value of $x$.